# Common Lisp: pass by value vs pass by reference

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I want to write a function in Common Lisp, which destructively modifies its argument. In C or Rust I would use a pointer/reference to an object, which can be dereferenced inside the body of the function. In CL I write:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (setf lst NIL))
```

But after evaluating this form:

```
(let ((obj (list "a" "b")))
  (foo obj)
  obj) => ("a" "b")
```

one sees that the function `foo` has no effect. I can explain that by pass by value semantic, where we modify a local copy of the argument pushed onto the function stack.
If we define another function:

```
(defun bar (lst)
  (setf (car lst) NIL))
```

and evaluate a similar form

```
(let ((obj (list "a" "b")))
  (bar obj)
  obj) => (NIL "b")
```

we will clearly see that the `lst` was modified as if we would use the pass by reference semantic. So, `(setf lst NIL)` did not worked but `(setf (car lst) NIL)` did. Could you please explain why?

Comment: The problem is with `setf`. It's first argument requires a `place`. In `foo` the symbol `lst` goes out of context, but in `bar` the place still exists in outer context.

Comment: `setf` with a symbol as place means you want to mutate what the variable is pointing at, not the object it is bound to. Eg. `lst = 0` is the same as `(setf lst nil)`. `lst` is an object so `(setf (car lst) ...)` mutates the car accessor of the object, thus yo uare now updating the object  and not the binding.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp passes arguments by value, but in most cases (other than primitive value types like fixnums or floats) the value is a reference. This is the same way that most managed languages work (e.g. Java, Python, JS).

In the `LET`-form, the value of the variable `OBJ` is a reference to a list, not the list itself. That reference is passed by value, so that inside the functions, the value of the parameter `LST` is another reference to the same list.

In `FOO`, the reference value is replaced with `NIL`, but the list that was previously referred to is not touched at all. In `BAR`, the list is retrieved from the heap and its `CAR` is replaced with `NIL`. Since `OBJ` holds a reference to the same list, the modification affects it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. One thing remained not so clear. Can I decide myself, whether  `setf` should follow a pointer, retrieve an object from the heap and modify it, OR it should just modify its binding?  How to modify the function `foo` so that it does set its argument to NIL?

Comment: If you use a plain variable name as the place for `SETF`, it will always only modify the variable, not the object being referred to. To modify the object, you have to use some accessor (such as `CAR`, `CDR`, `AREF`, etc.). To get `FOO` to work like you want, you have to wrap the list in some kind of box object that you can then modify (e.g. a zero-rank array or a struct), but it's more idiomatic Lisp to just return the modified object as per [Rainer Joswig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801241/5747548).

Answer (score 4):

For some operations the usual style is this:

```
(let ((obj (list "a" "b")))
  (setf obj (nbar obj))  ; nbar is destructively modifying the list argument
  (foo obj))
```

Above uses `SETF` to use the return value to change the binding of `obj`, since the function `nbar` itself can't do it.

Since `NBAR` has no access to the lexical variable `obj` and thus can't change it, one is supposed to return the object from `NBAR` and then one sets the variable to the result value - overwriting the previous binding.

Examples, where this rule is applicable: calls to `sort`, `nreverse`, ...